Auth.js v5 Database Session Strategy for Credential Provider Returning Null
I'm currently working on implementing authentication in my nextjs 14 project using Auth.js v5  ,However, I am encountering an issue where the session always returns null(Only for Credential provider) in page.tsx
My Setup:

Auth.js Version: v5

Provider: Credential Provider

Session Strategy: Database

Framework: Nextjs 14

Database: Vercel's Postgres

Adapter: Prisma


Auth.ts
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Google from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import Github from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter'
import { db } from './lib/db'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { loginSchema } from './schema/zod-form'
import { getUserByEmail } from './data/user'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import { Adapter } from 'next-auth/adapters'
import { generateSessionToken } from './Action/token'
const Credential = Credentials({
  credentials: {
    username: { label: 'name' },
    email: { label: 'email', type: 'email' },
    password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' },
  },
  async authorize(credentials) {
    const validate = loginSchema.safeParse(credentials)
    if (!validate.success) return null
    const { email, password } = validate.data
    const user = await getUserByEmail(email)
    if (!user || !user.password) {
      return null
    }
    const passwordmatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if (passwordmatch) {
      await generateSessionToken(user.id)
      return user
    }
    return null
  },
})
const config = {
  providers: [Google, Github, Credential],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db) as Adapter,
  session: { strategy: 'database' },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.role = user.role
      console.log(user)
      return session
    },
  },
  trustHost: true,
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config)

I'm returning the user in the authorize function if it passes the conditions. Everything is working correctly, except I am not getting the sessions in the page.tsx file when invoking const session = await auth();.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

We need to manually handle session creation, encryption and sign out events when using the database strategy.

My Setup:

Auth.js Version: v5

Provider: Credential Provider

Framework: Nextjs 14

Adapter: Prisma

Database: vercel postgres ## important !! edge compatible ##



github link to auth project:https://github.com/Amith-AG/my-turborepo/tree/main/apps/auth
explaination:

jwt callback:

callback:{
 async jwt({ account, user, token }) {
      if (account?.provider === 'credentials') {
        const sessionToken = uuidv4()
        const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000)

        const session = await PrismaAdapter(db).createSession!({
          userId: user.id!,
          sessionToken,
          expires,
        })
        token.sessionId = session.sessionToken
      }
      return token
    },
...
...
}


if provider is credential then:
manually create session token and expire data
use prisma adapter to save it into db: PrismaAdapter(db).createSession({sessionData})
then return session token


session callback(not neccesary):

callback:{
...
...
session({ session }) {
      if (!session.user) return session
      const user = {
        id: session.user.id,
        name: session.user.name,
        email: session.user.email,
        emailVerified: session.user.emailVerified,
        image: session.user.image,
        role: session.user.role,
      }
      session.user = user
      return session
    },
  },

to add extra info to session data

jwt

  jwt: {
    async encode({ token }) {
      return token?.sessionId as unknown as string
    },
}

token parameter is from jwt callback and this set session token in browser

list of edge compatible database driver for prisma: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/deployment/edge/overview#which-database-drivers-are-edge-compatible
session strategy concept: https://authjs.dev/concepts/session-strategies
authjs with prisma and edege compatibility and workaround: https://authjs.dev/getting-started/adapters/prisma


That's great, thanks! I wish the library would not be this restrictive about it. A similar approach is is discussed in this video.

I had the same issue with authv5 and couldn't see why it didn't work in the docs. The next-auth v4 docs state that Credentials only support JWT tokens and the database strategy won't work (https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials).
I can't see it in the v5 docs but this page was updated today (https://authjs.dev/getting-started/authentication/credentials) and maybe they support it now?
Really hope they support it, was a deal breaker for me.

Yes, its possible. We need to manually create the session using the Prisma adapter method PrismaAdapter(db).createSession({ userId, sessionIdValue, expire }). You can refer to this discussion for more detailshttps://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4394#discussioncomment-9847531

Same problem with session strategy database (work only with strategy:'jwt')
session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },

